# when firebase mobile authentication charge me?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

as I understood firebase is free until reach 10k/month after that charging will start
my question is if (user A) registered using his phone number and did verification then fire base will charge 0.01 or 0.06$ according to his country
now this registered (user A) will do log in maybe more than time today  so the question is
do firebse will charge me every time the same user do log in ?
or it is only for the registration

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service-related question, not a programming question. We cannot answer questions about pricing, costs, licensing or other questions related to your specific account at an off-site service or vendor. Contact that vendor directly for those types of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation available at https://firebase.google.com/pricing, it's only the verification that counts (the SMS that it send to the user), this means that you'll only pay for the registration, not the login, if you don't use the SMS to login.